# Automatically Export Power BI Reports Into Excel

Tags: powerbi, export, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have created around 150 reports from Power BI Desktop and published in Power BI service(web). Now the requirement is to **export all the reports(as Excel) daily by End Of Day and place in SharePoint**. I did go through Power BI documentation and we did one sample export for Paginated Report but no help available for General Power BI reports. General Power BI reports can be extracted only as PDF but not as Excel.

Now I have below queries -

- *How do we convert all reports into Paginated? (Is there any automated way to take all validations from existing report and convert to Paginated Report?)*
- *Else how to export existing reports into SharePoint?*

Any reference links would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Paginated Reports are the perfect solution for Excel extracts. However, there is no automated way to convert Power BI reports into paginated. What you can do to make it easier is:

- Enable the performance analyzer in Power BI desktop and refresh your visual (that you need to make as a paginated report) and copy the query
- In the report builder, connect to your Power BI dataset (this will allow you to use the data model already created)
- Paste the query in the dataset.

This will atleast save you the trouble of rewritting the query.

Comment: Thanks, we converted all our reports into Power BI Paginated reports for exports. But it's costly to export 150 reports from the Power BI workspace to SharePoint. Would definitely like to hear about alternate approaches in future Power BI releases.